# R - Loop over subscript in plot function (simple beginner's qst)

Tags: r, graph, plot

My code looks as follows:

```
plotf = function(title=expression("Test"~a )){
   plot(cars)
   title(title)
}

foo = c('a[1]', 'a[2]')

for(i in 1:2){
   plotf(title=expression("Test"~foo[i] ))
}
```

For the first plot I would like to have a subscript 1 and for the scond one a subscript 2, how do I achieve that? I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Expressions are unevaluated so the `foo[i]` in your expression remains as symbols and calls and is not expanded to their value. Plus, if you want subscripts, you need to use expressions and not strings. Note that `"a[1]"` is different than `a[1]`; the former is a character value and the latter is actually a "call".

To dynamically build expressions, you can use `bquote()` or `substitute()` to insert parts dynamically. Here's an example using the former

```
foo = expression(a[1], a[2])

layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=1))
for(i in 1:2){
   plotf(title=bquote("Test"~.(foo[[i]]) ))
}
```

[image]

Here there's not really a need for the `foo` variable. You could just as easily do

```
for(i in 1:2){
   plotf(title=bquote("Test"~a[.(i)]) )
}
```